# Find the tail of array except first element

Tags: julia

Is there a method to get the tail of a collection(e.g. vector) i.e. the array except the first element. Currently, I have

```
tail(arr) = selectdim(arr, 1, 2:length(arr))

julia> c
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> tail(c)
2-element view(::Array{Int64,1}, 2:3) with eltype Int64:
 2
 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use the `end` keyword:

```
julia> c = [11,12,13]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 11
 12
 13

julia> c[2:end]
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 12
 13
```

Comment: Also `@view c[2:end]` if you want a `view` like in OP.